# Type.BaseType in Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

- In VS2013: Create a Portable Class Library
- Target .NET Framework 4.5, Windows Phone 8.1 & Windows 8
- Write the following code:

  ```
  public class Class1
  {
      public static Type GetBaseType(Type type)
      {
          return type.BaseType;
      }
  }
  ```

Observe that you cannot compile: "'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'BaseType' and no extension method 'BaseType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Strange since the MSDN documentation clearly states this property should be present:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not available in WinRT apps. Properties and methods supported in WinRT have this mentioned explicitly (look at the store icon) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx

This answer provides a workaround for WinRT - [What is the equivalent to Type.BaseType in WinRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807024/what-is-the-equivalent-to-type-basetype-in-winrt)

```
Type.GetTypeInfo().BaseType
```

Comment: Thanks, so because the same thing is done different in .NET and WinRT, there is no option to do this in a Portable Class Library. How wonderful.

Comment: I am not sure what happens if you use #ifdefs in PCL. Maybe it will work?